# How to count or sum distinct values when there is a risk of intersection?

Tags: oracle

Imagine I have a table with people and their features:

```
group    Name  red_hair tall blue_eyes programmer
1         Mark  1        1    0         1
1         Sean  1        0    1         0
1        Lucas  1        1    1         1
2        Linda  0        1    1         1
```

I would like to count how many people of specific sets of features are in every group. In other words, I would like to make some bins without counting a person multiple times.

There are 2^4 (16) possible combinations of those sets, but I don't need so much.

For example, if a person has red_hair I don't care whether he or she has blue eyes or he or she a programmer. This person goes to the red hair bin of this group. 
If a person is a programmer I don't care whether he or she is tall, but I don't want to count people who are already in a red hair bin. Because I have already counted them.

So I have a priority:

- Red hair people counts first
- Programmers second
- People with blue eyes third

Expected result of this dataset:

```
group red_hair_persons programmers blue_eyes_persons 
1     3                0           0
2     0                1           0
```

when I do this:

```
select group, count(case when red_hair = 1 then name end) as red_hair,
count(case when programmer = 1 and red_hair = 0 then name end) as programmers
from table
group by group
```

I fear that there would be some intersections. Or the logic with CASES would be so complex I could drown in it.
Am I right? 
If so how could I avoid them? Maybe I am doing everything wrong and there is a better way to do what I want to. I have an enormous table with many features in it and I don't want to screw up.

Comment: Post your expected results for this sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I understood it:

```
SQL> with test (cgroup, name, red_hair, tall, blue_eyes, programmer) as
  2    (select 1, 'mark' , 1, 1, 0, 1 from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'sean' , 1, 0, 1, 0 from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'lucas', 1, 1, 1, 1 from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'linda', 0, 1, 1, 1 from dual
  6    ),
  7  priority as
  8    (select t.*,
  9       case when red_hair   = 1 then 'A'
 10            when programmer = 1 then 'B'
 11            when blue_eyes  = 1 then 'C'
 12            else 'D'
 13       end priority
 14     from test t
 15    )
 16  select cgroup,
 17    sum(case when priority = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) red_hair,
 18    sum(case when priority = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) programmer,
 19    sum(case when priority = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) blue_eyes,
 20    sum(case when priority = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) other
 21  from priority
 22  group by cgroup;

    CGROUP   RED_HAIR PROGRAMMER  BLUE_EYES      OTHER
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3          0          0          0
         2          0          1          0          0

SQL>
```

- `priority` CTE puts every person into its priority group, based on their properties
- the final select counts (using `SUM` + `CASE`) them per group

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of simple math involved in the conditional aggregation:

```
select "group",
  sum("red_hair") red_hair_persons,
  sum((1 - "red_hair") * "programmer") programmers,
  sum((1 - "red_hair") * (1 - "programmer") * "blue_eyes") blue_eyes_persons
from tablename
group by "group"
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6e1f5e7d77b11af9bcc50b3c8ee3212b).
Results:

```
> group | RED_HAIR_PERSONS | PROGRAMMERS | BLUE_EYES_PERSONS
> ----: | ---------------: | ----------: | ----------------:
>     1 |                3 |           0 |                 0
>     2 |                0 |           1 |                 0
```

Comment: That is an interesting approach. Thank you!